# How can be the interview for scrum master job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, scrum

I've been software developer for more than 5 years, and get my Scrum Master certification, so I am applying for this job.

Even if I have 0 years experience as a scrum master, I've always been working in agile, following scrum framework as a developer.

I'll have some interviews, I'm sure that it will be theortical questions, but is it possible to have an idea of how a scrum master interview can be?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe going through the official docs might help you to prepare for some of the theoretical questions that might be asked during the interview for such a position - > https://scrumguides.org/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can never know what a potential employer will ask you during an interview. Obviously it will be something related to the job you are applying for, but you can never know exactly.

The problem with Scrum (and Agile in general) is that everyone creates their own version and builds their own understanding of the thing. Most environments are dysfunctional in some way - e.g. [ScrumBut](https://www.scrum.org/resources/what-scrumbut), or [Scrumerfall](https://scrumpig.wordpress.com/tag/scrumerfall/) - but they all call the thing they are doing Scrum (or say they are being Agile).

For these reasons, when you get asked the same question in multiple Scrum Master interviews, the same answer won't be correct in all of the situations. For example, a Scrum Master should not plan work for the team or assign them tasks, but I've been asked this question and when I said that sounds like what a traditional Project Manager does... "Bzzz... Wrong answer!"

For a Scrum Master position I would personally ask questions related to:

- what is Agile and the [Agile Manifesto](https://agilemanifesto.org/)
- how Agile compares to more traditional ways of managing projects (like [Waterfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model))
- other Agile methods besides Scrum (Kanban, XP, Lean, etc)
- [what is Scrum](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) (obviously), the roles, the events, the artifacts, etc.
- tools and practices usually accompanying Agile teams ([user stories](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories), [Story Points](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/what-are-story-points), [burn down charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart), etc).
- then I would ask what qualities and skills does a Scrum Master need to have to be successful at their job (these will mostly be discussions about soft skills - see image below)
- **then for the most part of the interview I would ask [behavioral interview questions](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/interviewing/most-common-behavioral-interview-questions-and-answers)**. As a Scrum Master you will deal with people stuff, process stuff, with impediments, etc. Your problem-solving skills need to be tailored for these sorts of situations. For this reason, most of the questions will probably be behavioral interview questions.

A good interviewer will ask such questions while framing them in the context of the Scrum events (like estimation and sprint planing, refinement, review, retrospectives, conflict navigation, empiricism, etc). The main directions of discussion will revolve around [these areas](https://agilecoachinginstitute.com/agile-coaching-resources/):

[image]

But like I said, many have their own understanding of what Scrum is. I've been asked about fixed-price contracts, Waterfall, roadmap building with [Gantt charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart), change request management, task scheduling, and so on.

Finally, I'm not sure about what your understanding of Agile and Scrum is (depending on what working environments you've dealt with), but make sure that at the end of the interview you ask your own set of questions to see if their environment matches your expectations.

Comment: "I've been asked about fixed-price contracts, Waterfall, roadmap building with Gantt charts, change request management, task scheduling" Fixed-price contracts can be Agile if the fixed price is for a fixed development time rather than a fixed product being delivered. All the others are Waterfall practices.

Comment: @nick012000: Agree on the comment regarding the fixed-price. But that was not the  situation but fixing all corners of the "iron triangle". They wanted the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Should also point out that even if you don't give them the answers they are looking for, it doesn't mean you did poorly on the interview. It just means you aren't what they are looking for. This can be a good thing. Neither you nor the employer are going to be happy if you aren't a good fit for the position. Keep applying until you find one that does fit.